# Turning 24V battery to 6V battery help

Tags: batteries, battery-operated

I have an old RC car I'm trying to get running again. It takes a 6V 600mAh NiCd battery that has a discharge rate of 150mA but doesn't work any more. I wish to replace it with a 24V dewalt battery I have. Initially i thought I could just use a simple resistor or make a voltage divider but from what I've read online it's not that easy. If anyone could offer any help or advice or at least point me in some direction of how I could solve my problem that would be wonderful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be easier to disassemble the pack into a low voltage array than use a DCDC regulator. But both options are available.

Comment: It would be far easier to replace it with a similar modern battery; NiCd is no longer easily available, but NiMH has very similar characteristics and is very easy to get.

Comment: Don't mess with the DeWalt battery.  Too much overhead for no return.   As @Hearth suggests, replace it with a 6V NiMH pack.  You can get them (and chargers) on Amazon for a few dollars.  Lots of different sizes available.   150mA is pretty low for an RC car as well, you sure about that?  Must be a very small car.

Comment: Is your DeWalt battery Li-Ion or NiCd ? Both types exist and the NiCd variety will be rather easy to convert (destructively) into 6V pack (or even four 6V packs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you to use 6V battery with similar ratings (maybe close to that as recommended by others). However, if you still determined to use 24V battery, I would suggest you to use 24VDC-6VDC buck converter to output the required voltage. You can check more about the buck converter here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have no knowledge or experience on diodes could you please recommend what diodes I could use in my case to produce the 6V ? Also, say i made a buck converter, could i power it using a bench power supply and achieve the desired load power?

Comment: If you have no prior knowledge of circuit design, I would suggest you to purchase an already available buck-converter from online stores. As far as power is concerned, YES, you can definitely power it from DC bench supply

Comment: Thank you Norman this was very helpful. I do have some experience with circuit design and knowledge from school so I will definitely be building a buck converter!